# Reset MySQL in app Azure username and password

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, in-app

I was attempting to change the username and password of the MySQL in-app database in my Azure web app. I mistakenly thought that by changing the connection string in MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini would change the password. I am wondering if there is a way to restore the original MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini file so I can get the password  and access the database. I also deleted the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt file.

Comment: Try delete `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` in the kudu console and restart the WebApp. After restarting, it will regenerate the password, it is the same with the one in `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini` file.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Sorry used the wrong file extension on the question, i changed the .ini and deleted the .txt

Comment: But seems no matter? If your goal is accessing the db, just modify the password in .ini file. It is also unnecessary to restore the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't need to restore the password, you could customize the database, username and password to be used.

In the [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app#can-i-customize-the-database-username-and-password-to-be-used):

> If you want to customize the database, username and password, after you have created a new database, add new username or update password, simply modify `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini` , remove `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` and restart the WebApps.

Comment: Yeah this is what I tried to do, but I failed to create the new database first so I have lost access to the mysql in app.

Comment: @Niwith Could you turn off the mysql in app in the portal and delete the `mysql` folder in the kudu, then turn on it and restart the web app? According to this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app#cannot-connect-to-mysql-invalid-settings-or-wrong-usernamepassword), if use wrong password, just  delete the .txt file and restart the web app, it will work fine.

Comment: And how do you access d:\home... through the portal?